# Need help on a logical issue

Tags: android, button, onclicklistener

According to my design i have 6 buttons and above those buttons 2 layouts in square shape (just like an empty boxes)

The buttons represent each color and a set of double value

for example:

```
5.0   => brown btn
25.0  => red btn
50.0  => black btn
75.0  => blue btn
100.0 => violet btn
200.0 => green btn
```

When the user clicks on a button and tap on any one of the empty box, the box gets filled with the corresponding double value for example I will explain this in each step:

1. if the user clicks on 25 (red button) and taps on any of the box, the box gets filled with 25 text and red color in background.
2. if the user again taps on the same box, the value will be incremented to 50(25+25), here i need the background color to be as black, as 50 represents black
3. Now if the user clicks on 5(brown button) and taps on the box filled with black color, the value will be incremented to 55(50+5), but the color must be as black only.
4. Now if the user starts tapping on the same box, the value will be incremented as +5, until the value reaches 75 the background color to be as black, exactly from 75 it must be as blue
5. In between if the user taps on the second box, it must be filled with color of the button which lastly get clicked.

Now I am just able to increment the values and fill ht colors on the boxes according to the buttons clicked, I want to know how to fill the colors when the values get incremented

How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i got the solution by this way

```
Iterator<Integer> iter = values.iterator();
         int small=0 , bigger=0;
         while (iter.hasNext())
         {
             Integer currElement = iter.next();
             if (z.compareTo(currElement) > -1)
             {
                 small = currElement;
             }
             else
             {
                 bigger = currElement;
             }            
         }

         System.out.println("small "+small);
         System.out.println("biggest "+bigger);

         for(int i=0; i< values.size(); i++)
         {
             if(small == values.get(i))
             {
                if(i == 0)
                 {
                     Log.i("", "brwon");
                     break;
                 }
                 else if(i == 1)
                 {
                     Log.i("", "red");
                     break;
                 }
                 else if(i == 2)
                 {
                     Log.i("", "black");
                     break;
                 }
                 else if(i == 3)
                 {
                     Log.i("", "blue");
                     break;
                 }
                 else if(i == 4)
                 {
                     Log.i("", "violet");
                     break;
                 }
                 else if(i == 5)
                 {
                     Log.i("", "green");
                     break;
                 }
             }
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming here that you are just looking for alogical hint.

Maintain a class variable lastVal. Set its value -1 initially.

You can maintain an array containing the values of the boxes.

Whenever a user clicks a box you increase the box value in array with the lastVal.

Here is a simple class....this is not a complete class, just a reference to what I mean to explain.

```
public class MyClass{

    int lastVal = -1;
    int boxVal[10];
    View box[10];

    void handleColorClick(int keyVal)
    {
        lastVal = keyVal;

    }


    void handleBoxClick(int index)
    {
       boxVal[index] += lastVal;
       setBoxBackground(index)


    }

    void setBoxBackground(int index)
    {
       //check if the box color is matching any fixed color then set the background here
    }


}
```